# Matlab: Is there any difference between the use of square brackets for declaring a list or not?

Tags: matlab

We can specify a list by `a = [1:3]`
but at the same time,
we can also specify a list by `a = 1:3`.

I see that the output on the command window for `a` is the same, i.e.

`a = 
     1 2 3`

But is there any difference in the internal structure where we cannot see and cause difference in further calculation?

Comment: Everything is stored as an `m x n` matrix in MATLAB. So there is no difference according to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think so.  In MATLAB, the square brackets can be used for concatenating some number of matrices together.  So for example, I could do

```
x = [1:2, 5:7, 9:12]
x =

    1    2    5    6    7    9   10   11   12
```

In your case, you are doing matrix concatenation with only one matrix, which simply yields the matrix provided.

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need to go to vectors. Even for scalars, the following are equivalent:

```
a = 123;
a = [ 123 ];
```

The first one declares `a` as the scalar `123`, while the second one declares it as a length-1 vector whose sole element is `123`. In MATLAB, these two are exactly the same thing.

Here's an example (using octave):

```
octave:1> x = 123
x =  123
octave:2> x(2) = 456
x =

   123   456
```

As you can see, what was declared as a scalar could very easily be handled as a vector. I think everything is just stored as vectors.